# passing variable to an activity through an Intent is always the same

Tags: android, variables, notifications, android-intent, android-c2dm

My application receives a C2DM message and sends a status bad notification with the C2DM message. So far so good.
When the user clicks on the notification, an activity is called, passing the C2DM message as a variable.

Now, the first time it works smoothly, the second time the variable passed is not refreshed. It's always the first variable passed.
Am I missing something?

Here are the snipperts:

C2DM Notification

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BMBPad.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("seqid", message);              
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

This is how I read the variable in the Activity called by the Intent.

```
extra = this.getIntent().getExtras();
seqidi = extra.getString("seqid");
```

Anyone any idea why that happens?

Comment: First, could you clarify your question with code quotes, to style the snippet out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

In your case:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Please also have a look here: [Android PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to append this snippet in the Activity called by the Intent.

```
/**
 * Override super.onNewIntent() to let getIntent() fetch the latest intent
 * that was used to start this Activity rather than the first intent.
 */
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override onNewIntent() method, get your variable like this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
super.onNewIntent(intent);
seqid = intent.getStringExtra("seqid","");
```

}

because start the activity again will trigger onNewIntent() method.